# Aggregate horizontal SQL data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to summarize data that is scaled out horizontally in a Microsoft SQL database.

```
+-------+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------+
| JOB   | DATE    | CC1_CODE | CC1_HRS | CC2_CODE | CC2_HRS | CC3_CODE | CC3_HRS |
+-------+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------+
| A1234 | 12/1/16 | 0100     | 6       | 0300     | 2       | NULL     | 0       |  
+-------+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------+
| A1234 | 12/1/16 | 0200     | 8       | NULL     | 0       | NULL     | 0       |
+-------+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------+     
| A1234 | 12/1/16 | 0100     | 4       | 0200     | 2       | 0300     | 2       |
+-------+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------+
```

Desired results would be - group by JOB and DATE, then summarize all the HRS by CODE.

```
+-------+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------+
| JOB   | DATE    | CC1_CODE | CC1_HRS | CC2_CODE | CC2_HRS | CC3_CODE | CC3_HRS |
+-------+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------+
| A1234 | 12/1/16 | 0100     | 10      | 0200     | 10      | 0300     | 4       |  
+-------+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------+
```

Notes - columns actually go from CC1 to CC25.  CC_CODES can be stored in any of the CC_CODES fields, it just depends on which on gets enter first.

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: How is this being "aggregated"?  CC3_HRS column 0+0+2 <> 4.  What's happening in that column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yucky data format.  One method is to unpivot the data and then re-aggregate:

```
select job, date, code, sum(hrs) as hrs
from t cross apply
     (values (CC1_CODE, CC1_HRS),
             (CC2_CODE, CC2_HRS),
             . . .
     ) c(code, hrs)
group by job, date, code;
```

I see no reason to continue trying to process data in that format.  The above returns data on separate rows.

But, if you really must, here is a method using conditional aggregation (and the above query):

```
with a as (
      select job, date, code, sum(hrs) as hrs,
             row_number() over (partition by job, date order by code) as seqnum
      from t cross apply
           (values (CC1_CODE, CC1_HRS),
                   (CC2_CODE, CC2_HRS),
                   . . .
           ) c(code, hrs)
      group by job, date, code
     )
select job, date,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then code end) as code_01,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then hrs end) as hrs_01,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then code end) as code_02,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then hrs end) as hrs_02,
       . . .
from a
group by job, date;
```